# Include column names in query results or query comparison

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, associative-array

I am using the below to compare two select results and to display the differences between them.
It works as expected but **I am unable to also include the corresponding column names**.

Can someone tell me how I have to amend my code to get the desired result as in the example below?

**PHP:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE vstId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vstId);
$stmt->execute();
$resultBefore = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->close();

// some event

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE vstId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vstId);
$stmt->execute();
$resultAfter = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close(); 

for($i=0; $i<count($resultAfter); $i++) {
    if($resultAfter[$i] != $resultBefore[$i]) {
        $diff.= '<tr><td>' . $resultBefore[$i] . '</td><td>' . $resultAfter[$i] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '<table>' . $diff . '</table>';
```

**Current result:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>10408</td><td>10407</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>168</td><td>167</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column name that changed</td><td>10408</td><td>10407</td> // I am missing the 1st td
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column name that changed</td><td>168</td><td>167</td> // I am missing the 1st td
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just use `fetch_assoc` instead of `fetch_row` and change your `for` loop to `foreach ($resultBefore as $key => $value)` then replace `$i` in your existing loop with `$key` and output `$key` where you want "Column name that changed"

Comment: The only difference I see is indeed missing the first td. But it's plain text? Just add it after diff .= ?

Comment: @Nick: Thanks a lot. Will try thatt.

Comment: @Wimanicesir: Seriously ? I mean the actual column name, not a plain text..

Comment: @keewee279 was going to respond to your prior question but you deleted it before I had a chance...

Comment: Thanks, Nick - I appreciate it ! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @keewee279, haha ok that makes a lot more sense XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_row()`. It will return an associative array. Then use `foreach` loop and the associative key to loop the array and compare the elements.

Also, remove `store_result()`, you already used `get_result()`.

Fixed code would look like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE vstId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vstId);
$stmt->execute();
$resultBefore = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

// some event

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE vstId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vstId);
$stmt->execute();
$resultAfter = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($resultAfter as $col_name => $value) {
    if ($value !== $resultBefore[$col_name]) {
        $diff .= '<tr><td>' . htmlentities($col_name) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($resultBefore[$col_name]) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($value) . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '<table>' . $diff . '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This does not work as it duplicates all rows in the final result.

Comment: What do you mean it duplicates rows? Are you sure you are looping only once?

Comment: Using this returns every result row twice, once with the column name and once with the numeric id from the array. Maybe because the first array is not assigned to $col_name => $value ?

Comment: @keewee279 My bad, sorry for confusion. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Dharman. This shows the correct column names and does not duplicate the rows anymore but it returns only one column of values which contains all values from $resultAfter, instead of two columns with a comparison of $resultBefore and $resultAfter. I am looking for a way to get three columns, 1st for column name (we have that now), 2nd for value before and 3rd for value after.

Comment: Value before should be in `$resultBefore[$col_name]` and the value after in `$resultAfter[$col_name]` or in `$value`

Comment: That was it - now it works perfect. Thanks a lot for all your time !